# Не работает text-alight: justify

Tags: html, css

Что я делаю неправильно? Почему блоки не распределили отступы вокруг себя ровно?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: justify;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить свойство text-align-last

Comment: text-align: justify; выравнивает текст, а не блоки div

Answer (score 2):

Псевдоэлемент `:after` решает

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: justify;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
 }

 .block {
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px solid blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
</div>
```

Еще твой вопрос решится и заменяя `text-align:justify` на `text-align-last:justify` , но будет проблемы с [поддержкой на браузерах](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-align-last)

Answer (score 1):

Для манипуляций с блочными элементами используйте `display: flex;`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
  <div class="block">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не подходит, нужна поддержка IE9

Comment: Для ИЕ используйте `<table>` если у `<td>` не указывать размер, то они распределятся по ширине таблицы

Comment: @UModeL посмотри, пожалуйста VK