# Почему не работает text-align: justify конкретно в верстке?

Tags: html, css

Имеется верстка: https://uzinouzi.github.io/ttt/

Внизу есть блок с иконками, они должны распространиться на всю ширину родительского блока, но этого не происходит, не понимаю почему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я вставляю идентичный код в песочницу, а там он работает:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZYGgV

```css
.social-network {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  width: 100%;
}

.social-network__item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.social-network__item--vk {
  background-color: #6996c7;
}

.social-network__item--fb {
  background-color: #496194;
}

.social-network__item--ok {
  background-color: #ff9c43;
}

.social-network__item--in {
  background-color: #cebfa9;
}

.social-network__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-network">
  <div class="social-network__item social-network__item--vk">
    <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-vk"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="social-network__item social-network__item--fb">
    <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="social-network__item social-network__item--ok">
    <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-odnoklassniki"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="social-network__item social-network__item--in">
    <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-instagram"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Также я заметил, что по какой-то причине между inline-block'ами нет текстовых узлов, вообще нигде, это по сути то хорошо, но с другой стороны я не знаю почему так произошло и возможно, что это и есть причина, по которой не работает свойство `text-align: justify;`

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что этот вопрос клон  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878730/Не-работает-text-alight-justify

Comment: Зачем плодить одинаковые вопросы?

Comment: @Air вопросы отличаются. Решение из упомянутого вами вопроса этот вопрос НЕ решает.

Answer (score 2):

Когда в строке только одно слово, `text-align: justify` и `text-align-last: justify` прижимают его [к левому краю](https://webref.ru/css/text-align-last):

> Строка выравнивается по ширине. Если в последней строке только одно слово, то оно будет выравнено по левому краю.

Между инлайн-блоками в песочнице пробелы есть, и они нормально распределяются по ширине строки. А на вашем сайте пробелов между блоками нет, поэтому инлайн-блоки слиплись в единственное слово и прижались влево.

Вот убираю пробелы, и блоки слипаются:

```css
.social-network {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  width: 100%;
}

.social-network__item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.social-network__item--vk {
  background-color: #6996c7;
}

.social-network__item--fb {
  background-color: #496194;
}

.social-network__item--ok {
  background-color: #ff9c43;
}

.social-network__item--in {
  background-color: #cebfa9;
}

.social-network__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-network">
  <div class="social-network__item social-network__item--vk">
    <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-vk"></i>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="social-network__item social-network__item--fb">
    <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="social-network__item social-network__item--ok">
    <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-odnoklassniki"></i>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="social-network__item social-network__item--in">
    <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-instagram"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как показать HTML на гитхабе без потери пробелов, не знаю. Можно добавить эти пробелы скриптом. Но проще всего, наверное, использовать флексбокс:

```css
.social-network {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.social-network__item {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.social-network__item--vk {
  background-color: #6996c7;
}

.social-network__item--fb {
  background-color: #496194;
}

.social-network__item--ok {
  background-color: #ff9c43;
}

.social-network__item--in {
  background-color: #cebfa9;
}

.social-network__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-network">
  <div class="social-network__item social-network__item--vk">
    <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-vk"></i>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="social-network__item social-network__item--fb">
    <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="social-network__item social-network__item--ok">
    <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-odnoklassniki"></i>
  </div><!--
  --><div class="social-network__item social-network__item--in">
    <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-instagram"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Была подобная тема только что. Также можно решить это псевдоэлементом `:after` без `text-align-last`

```
.social-network {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:justify;
 }

.social-network:after { 
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```css
.social-network {
  width: 100%;
  text-align:justify;
}

.social-network:after { 
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}



.social-network__item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.social-network__item--vk {
  background-color: #6996c7;
}
.social-network__item--fb {
  background-color: #496194;
}
.social-network__item--ok {
  background-color: #ff9c43;
}
.social-network__item--in {
  background-color: #cebfa9;
}
.social-network__icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-network">
    <div class="social-network__item social-network__item--vk">
          <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-vk"></i></div>
    <div class="social-network__item social-network__item--fb">
          <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-facebook-f"></i></div> 
    <div class="social-network__item social-network__item--ok">
          <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-odnoklassniki"></i></div> 
    <div class="social-network__item social-network__item--in">
          <i class="social-network__icon fab fa-instagram"></i></div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Вопрос в том и состоит,  что ваше решение не сработало. Уберите пробелы между блоками в вашем коде, и они прижмутся влево. См. мой ответ рядом.

Comment: Да, есть такое.